# How to fix this should only be called when the cursor is valid using ExpandableListView

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, simplecursortreeadapter

Hi i am using ExpandableListView with AsyncQueryHandler as given in google android samples.
But i am getting some exception saying this should only be called when the cursor is valid

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(28265): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(28265): java.lang.IllegalStateException: this should only be called when the     cursor is valid
 E/AndroidRuntime(28265):   at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter.getGroupView(CursorTreeAdapter.java:198) E/AndroidRuntime(28265):   at    android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
 E/AndroidRuntime(28265):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2290)
 E/AndroidRuntime(28265):   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
 E/AndroidRuntime(28265):   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
  E/AndroidRuntime(28265):  at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1330)
 E/AndroidRuntime(28265):   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1600)
/AndroidRuntime(28265):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2141)
 E/AndroidRuntime(28265):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13844)
 E/AndroidRuntime(28265):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
 E/AndroidRuntime(28265):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1003)
 E/AndroidRuntime(28265):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13844)
```

I am really not able to find a solution or hack to fix this issue

I am also trying to query db inside adapters like this

```
    @Override
    protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor,
            boolean isLastChild) {
        super.bindChildView(view, context, cursor, isLastChild);
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setTag(""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CategorySub.Columns.KEY)));
    }
```

and

```
    @Override
    protected void bindGroupView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor,
            boolean isExpanded) {
        super.bindGroupView(view, context, cursor, isExpanded);
    /*  TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTag(""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CategoryPrimary.Columns.KEY)));

        if (cursor.getPosition() % 2 != 0) {
            lblListHeader
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.group_normal_first);

        } else {
            lblListHeader
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.group_normal_second);
        }*/
    }
```

Does this makes problem ?